# mysql replace text

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have this uncomplete query:

```
update `wp_posts` set `post_content` = replace(`post_content`, 'src="/uploads/*"', 'src="blog/uploads/*"');
```

In the field post_content I have some html code.
I want to search for src="/uploads/*", * = any image.
And replace it with src="blog/uploads/*" and keep the image;

How to do this?

Thanks

example text:

```
<p><strong><em>De tips en tricks, die in de Flexmailblog worden meegegeven, zijn een handig vertrekpunt voor de e-mailmarketeer. Maar hoe ziet de ideale e-mailcampagne er nu precies uit? </em></strong></p><br /><!-- s9ymdb:138 --><img class="serendipity_image_center" width="400" height="519" style="border: 0px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;" src="/uploads/asu_example.jpg" alt="" /><!--more--><br /><br />
<div align="justify">Laten we beginnen door de illusie alvast te doorprikken: een ideale e-mailcampagne bestaat niet. Maar e-mailmarketeers kunnen na een grondige analyse van de positieve en de ‘pijnpunten’ van de campagne hun conclusies trekken. Perfect bestaat dan wel niet, maar het kan wel benaderd worden. 
 <br /><br />In deze blogpost zetten we de tering naar de nering. We nemen er een e-mailcampagne van de Amerikaanse vrijwilligersorganisatie Arizona State University (ASU) in the Community bij. De organisatie stuurt twee keer per maand een nieuwsbrief uit om het stafpersoneel, de studenten en de leden van de gemeenschap te informeren over de laatste nieuwtjes. Het doel van de communicatie is het aandikken van de participatie. Vandaag bespreken we de positieve elementen. <br /><br /><strong>Zichtbaar<br /></strong><br />De ‘Join mailing list’-knop is duidelijk zichtbaar en beantwoordt aan één van de sleutelobjectieven van de e-mailcommunicatie namelijk meer inschrijvingen genereren op de nieuwsbrief. Wanneer de nieuwsbrief doorgestuurd wordt naar het netwerk van de ontvanger kan de begunstigde zich meteen inschrijven. <br /><br /><strong>Brand identity<br /></strong><br />Het toevoegen van het logo van de organisatie geeft de nieuwsbrief een sterke <em>brand identity</em>. Het logo is meteen herkenbaar voor de ontvangers, waardoor ze de nieuwsbrief niet gaan categoriseren onder junkmail. <br /><br /><strong>Aandacht trekken<br /></strong><br />De verzender maakt gebruik van een afbeelding om aandacht te trekken naar het belangrijkste artikel van de nieuwsbrief. Afbeeldingen zijn bovendien handig om een groot tekstblok op te breken. <br /><br /><strong>Structuur<br /></strong><br />De nieuwsbrief wordt ingedeeld in verschillende tekstvakken met een eigen achtergrondkleur. Op die manier voeg je structuur toe aan je e-mailcampagne. Bovendien is het voor de ontvanger gemakkelijker om de nieuwsbrief te scannen op content die voor hem interessant is.  <br /><br /><strong>Linken<br /></strong><br />De verzender heeft een link toegevoegd in de nieuwsbrief. Dat is een absolute must. Je kan immers niet altijd voorspellen hoe de e-mailcampagne er gaat uitzien in de verschillende e-mailcliënten. Een link, die de ontvanger naar je website verwijst,  kan dat voor je oplossen. Voeg een archief nieuwsbrieven toe aan je website zodat je ontvanger de originele versie daar kan bezichtigen.<br /><br />Volg ons en ontdek de Flexmailtips om de e-mailcampagne te verbeteren.

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`, 'src="/uploads/', 'src="blog/uploads/');
```

Comment: wait it is doing somehting I made a backup of the table and was doing it on the wrong one sorry

Comment: Did the example text come from reading text from the post_content field of wp_posts?

Comment: the example text is the value of one post_content field, I got it now thanks